# 1 part of case clause not working correctly

Tags: sql, t-sql, date, time, case

im having a little trouble with a case clause. The problem is in the last portion ending in DueBeyond, i need this to return any of our orders in our system that is due beyond tomorrow, as in 2 days from today. sorry to be overly obvious.

```
SUM(CASE WHEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP > oi.RequiredByDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as PastDue
,SUM(CASE WHEN DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, oi.RequiredByDate), 0) = dateadd(day,     datediff(day, '19000101',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),'19000102') then 1 ELSE 0 END) as DueTomorrow
,SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.TruncateDate(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) = dbo.TruncateDate(oi.RequiredByDate) THEN 1 Else 0 END) as DueToday
,SUM(CASE WHEN DateDiff(day, getdate(), RequiredByDate) BETWEEN 2 and 7 AND DateName(weekday, RequiredByDate) = 'Monday' Then 1 ELSE 0 END) as DueMonday
,SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.TruncateDate(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) <= dbo.TruncateDate(oi.RequiredByDate) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as DueBeyond
```

Comment: What's the problem? Some sample input and expected/actual output would help make this question answerable.

Comment: sorry for the lack of data kinda new to this

Comment: im on sql server 2005, i want this to count clients orders in our database based on their expected delivery date and tell me in a table how many of each clients orders are in each delivery status(due today, past due, etc) the only columns i need are clients.name and the created columns from the case clauses. i am transferring this data to a bar and/or pie chart in vs 2010 using telerik reporting. do you need any more info?

Answer (score 0):

If you add two days to the current date and then see if that is still less than or equal to your required date it must be no sooner than two days in the future.

```
,SUM(CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY, 2,dbo.TruncateDate(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) <= 
     dbo.TruncateDate(oi.RequiredByDate) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as DueBeyond
```

Comment: thanks but now i have a new issue, i have this and another query which need to be returning the same data. one or both of these is incorrect but i cant tell which.  can you tell?

Comment: SELECT cl.Name as Client, clb.Name as ClientBranch
,
 CASE 
  WHEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP > oi.RequiredByDate THEN 'Past Due'
  WHEN dbo.TruncateDate(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) = dbo.TruncateDate(oi.RequiredByDate) THEN 'Due Today'
  WHEN DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, oi.RequiredByDate), 0) = dateadd(day, datediff(day, '19000101',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),'19000102') then 'Due Tomorrow'
  WHEN DateDiff(day, getdate(), RequiredByDate) BETWEEN 2 and 7 AND DateName(weekday, RequiredByDate) = 'Monday' Then 'Due Monday'
  WHEN DATEADD(DAY, 2,dbo.TruncateDate(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) <=

Comment: dbo.TruncateDate(oi.RequiredByDate) THEN 'Due Beyond'
  ELSE 'Something is wrong with this Report' END
  AS DeliveryStatus
  
FROM OrderItems oi
JOIN Orders o ON o.OrderID = oi.OrderID
JOIN Counties c ON c.FIPS = o.FIPS
JOIN Clients cl ON cl.ClientID = o.ClientID
JOIN Milestones m ON m.MilestoneID = oi.LastMilestoneID
JOIN Products p ON p.ProductID = oi.ProductID
JOIN Vendors v ON v.VendorID = oi.VendorID
LEFT JOIN ClientBranches clb ON clb.ClientID = o.ClientID


WHERE QueueID > 0

Comment: with cte AS (SELECT cl.Name,
    
    SUM(CASE WHEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP > oi.RequiredByDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as PastDue
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, oi.RequiredByDate), 0) = dateadd(day, datediff(day, '19000101',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),'19000102') then 1 ELSE 0 END) as DueTomorrow
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.TruncateDate(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) = dbo.TruncateDate(oi.RequiredByDate) THEN 1 Else 0 END) as DueToday
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN DateDiff(day, getdate(), RequiredByDate) BETWEEN 2 and 7 AND DateName(weekday, RequiredByDate) = 'Monday' Then 1 ELSE 0 END) as DueMonday

Comment: ,SUM(CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY, 2,dbo.TruncateDate(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) <= dbo.TruncateDate(oi.RequiredByDate) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as DueBeyond
    
    
 
 
 
 

 
 
FROM OrderItems oi
JOIN Orders o ON o.OrderID = oi.OrderID
JOIN Counties c ON c.FIPS = o.FIPS
JOIN Clients cl ON cl.ClientID = o.ClientID
JOIN Milestones m ON m.MilestoneID = oi.LastMilestoneID
JOIN Products p ON p.ProductID = oi.ProductID
JOIN Vendors v ON v.VendorID = oi.VendorID
LEFT JOIN ClientBranches clb ON clb.ClientID = o.ClientID
WHERE QueueID > 0 
GROUP BY cl.Name 



)

Select * FROM cte

Comment: @wondergoat77, did I answer correctly your posted question about getting DueBeyond to work? If so, we should complete this question and then you can start a brand new one as your follow-up question looks very different.

Comment: turns out this one isnt quite figured out, the Due Beyond portion of the clause still isnt working correctly as it is picking up all orders due monday and putting them into due beyond, i also have a couple orders falling into past due and due today.  Ive tried converting the datetime format to match to eliminate variables but its not working the way i expect it to.  Any ideas? need more info?

Comment: @wondergoat77, I would create a function from this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10641/Optimized-Calculation-Algorithm-for-Business-Days) which computes the number of business days. Then you can call that to see if the RequiredDate is 2 business days away from the current date, which I think is what you're looking for.